# share me the details or share the details with me?

Tags: grammar

Can anyone please tell me which of the following is correct?

1. Share me the (or your) details

Or

2. Share the (or your) details with me.

Thank you

Comment: Share me your details is another example of Indianism(I'm from India), where some speakers are influenced by their mother tongue and fail to apply the grammar rules in English. It is a widely used phrase which is wrong. "*Please share the details with me*" is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The following is *incorrect*:

- Share me the details.
- Share me your details.

The following ways are *correct*:

- Share *with* me the details.
- Share *with* me your details.
- Share the details with me.
- Share your details with me.

Be that as it may, I have been hearing young people say things like, "Share me your details."  I think that this syntactical error has come about as a result of technology, particularly in regard to computer networks and using the verb "share" for the action of granting users permission to access files on a network.  In this context, you may here people say things like, "Will you share me that file."  However, this doesn't mean, "Will you share it with me."  It means, "Will you logon and make the computer inputs needed for me to access this file?"

Answer (score 0):

The first one is wrong.
The second one is awkward.

Do consider this:

> Mind sharing the details?

Answer (score 0):

*Share the details with me* is acceptable, particularly if asked as a question.

Comment: Actually, it's "Verb, IO, DO," which can be idiomatic ("Give me the ball") except that with *share* the indirect object requires a preposition. It's the missing preposition which is the problem.

Comment: @Andrew Leach True!  I'll edit to correct.